Dependency ':flutter_local_notifications' requires core library desugaring to be enabled for :app
I'm trying to run this ready-made app, but it wasn't working, so I had to update the AGP. After doing that, I keep getting this error. I'm a novice with Dart and Android, so...
please let me know if you need more info, I included the versions I'm using.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

       1.  Dependency ':flutter_local_notifications' requires core library desugaring to be enabled
           for :app.

           See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html for more
           details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2s

flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4317], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable at C:\flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 84a1e904f4 (1 year, 6 months ago), 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
    • Engine revision d44b5a94c9
    • Dart version 3.0.0
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

[√] VS Code (version 1.95.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.100.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4317]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 122.0.6261.112
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 130.0.2849.68

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

app\bulid.gradle
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "code_level_1"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.dbestech.shop_app_code_level_1"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}


android\bulid.gradle

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


I tried a few solutions such as this but nothing have worked.

Can you share your build.gradle files?

@tomerpacific I added it.

In android/app/build.gradle update the following things, according to your dependencies
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    // For AGP 7.4+
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3'
    // For AGP 7.3
    // coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.3'
    // For AGP 4.0 to 7.2
    // coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.9'
}

and boom! it worked for me.
For more info you can visit official docs - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#groovy

Saved My Time. Thanks Mate

You are missing several key steps in the integration. Based on the documentation, you need to do the following for Android:

Add the following inside your app level build.gradle file:
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
}


Use either gradle version 7.3.1 or higher
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'


Add these libraries to avoid specific crashes on Android 12L devices
dependencies {
     implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
     implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
}


Make sure your compileSdkVersion is at least 34


I also wrote an article about integrating flutter local notifications which you can read here.
And you can see the source code of an application I made which integrated flutter local notifications here.

I did what you said, even clean and re-run it, but I'm still getting the same damn error. Honestly, this app’s about to drive me crazy.

@Blaine.devon - Can you update the files in your question to reflect that changes you made?

You need to enable coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true . this is the missing one.
 compileOptions {
    // Enable core library desugaring to support Java 8+ language features
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true  

    // Set Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}



dependencies   {
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
}


In your android/app/build.gradle add coreLibraryDesugaring inside dependencies:
dependencies {
    // Add this [coreLibraryDesugaring] inside [dependencies]
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4'
}

This will enable core library desugaring.

thank you for answering but It didn't work, still getting the error.

same error or different?

the exact same.
